# Getting data with Facebook Graph Api

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get all the facebook group members ids with facebook php sdk, I am getting an array, and can't get out of the array with only ids.

Here is my array:

```
Array
(
[data] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [name] => Name Surname
                [administrator] => 
                [id] => 655330041265756
            )

        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [name] => Name Surname2
                [administrator] => 
                [id] => 10206563909924840
            )

        [2] => stdClass Object
            (
                [name] => Name Surname3
                [administrator] => 
                [id] => 1035931373098451
            )
```

I am trying to export only `[id]`, how is this possible?

Comment: Are you searching for an id, or do you want to only return an id?

Comment: I need to get ids and echo facebook images, I don't know how to export only [id] from this array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a simple foreach can be used to iterate through the array and extract the id from each object.

```
foreach ($array as $key=>$value) {
    echo $value->id;
}
```

*Edit:* If you want to assign the ids to an array, use the following code:

```
foreach ($array as $key=>$value) {
     $idArray[] = $value->id;
}
```

Where $idArray is your array of ids.

Comment: unfortunately it returns nothing. I would like to echo lets say third element of an array like
         echo ($graphObject['data']->id[2]->id) and it also returns nothing, I think it's something different because of my array, you can see how it looks above. Thanks!

Comment: Ah, I see. You just need to run the foreach on the array (with key "data") within the parent array.

foreach($array['data'] as $key=>$value) { ...

Comment: No problem. For future reference, $var['element'] drills down into an array. $var->element drills down into an object.